# Pip install failure - Known Bug

Tags: pip, ubuntu-14.04

As of this week my vagrant builds are no longer working because of a pip error which is happening whenever I build a new machine, my existing machines have a working copy of pip.  I'm provisioning `vagrant machines with ubuntu/trusty64 and the first command is:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

However after running `sudo pip install something` fails with the error

```
ImportError:No module packaging.version.  
command/usr/binpython -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=`/tmp/pip_build_root/defusexml/setup.py'; exec(compil(getattr(tokenize, 'open')(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec')) install --record /tmp/pip-wVb4Du-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with erro code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/defusedxml Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log
```

I've spun up a new machine and installed pip it installs with no errors.  This is a new problem I've been provisioning machines with the same file for the past 6 months.  Is there a way to fix this, have they changed a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more research it turns out this is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1658844 that has recently been introduced.

The workaround is to install pip with easy_install via python-setuptools and pip will work.

Comment: Followed the links a couple deep. I'm on linux and I needed to remove my apt version of python-pip and then run this script: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. Followed instructions found here: https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel, linked from here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/937.